# Rigging my human armature makes eyes be sucked into the skull

Tags: rigging, armature

I've been following a course on Udemy and I got to the part where I have to parent my mesh to a rig with automatic weights right after rigging the default human armature in blender 2.79. The problem is that my rig ended up looking like in pic related, where the eyelids have been sucked into the skull through the eye-sockets and the eye themselves have the bone pointing inwards instead of outwards. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The rig's bones are pointing inwards, isntead of outwards]

[image: This is how it looks after I parent to rig]

[image: The eye and the bone placement before parenting]

EDIT: 
1) The problem seems to start as soon as I press the 'Generate rig' button. The bones deform at that moment, without even allowing me to parent the mesh first, in fact, when I parent the mesh to the unrigged armature, the thing works completely fine...

[image: After-Before]

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the pictures, I am not positive but it could be that you need to fix the weight paint issues. Select the rig in Pose Mode and then Shift select the model (both should be selected) then go into Weight Paint (its in the Object/Edit mode menu. From there you can right click on whatever bone and see the weight influence. Red= full control and Blue is unaffected. If the eye are red then you can pull up the paint menu with T and select the Subtract brush. (Default is Draw). Weight is 1.0 meaning you will paint red and 0 is blue meaning you will kill the influence of the bone on the mesh. So if you lighten the color of the mesh affected by the eyebone then it should fix the problem.

If all that wasn't the issue, then try to delete doubles. Make sure your mesh has no double verts. Un-parent the mesh (Alt+P), delete all the vertex groups (go to the vertex tab it is next to the materials tab) and then select the mesh and press W and remove doubles. Then parent the mesh to the armature again. The order in case you messed it up is, select the mesh (child) then shift select the armature (parent) hit Ctrl+P parent with auto weights. Hopefully that fixes your issue. Please respond if it helped you fix your problem.

Comment: No, that didn't fix it T.T, it seems that the problem comes from the rigging itself. The eye bone flips inwards and the eyelid bones go berserk as soon as I press the 'generate rig' button. Parenting, for now, has nothing to do with the deformation... thanks for the comment though anything helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Automatic weights are not sufficient for eyes.  You need to be adjusting your weights kinda manually.  The rim of the eyelid needs to be *fully* weighted to eyelid bones, and you're probably not going to get that with just autoweights.
2. The one picture where it looks like we can see the rest pose of the bones that actually deform the eyelid is the left side of the fourth picture.  But those bones only barely follow the eyelid.  If you have a ring of bones, and you want autoweights to be close, these bones need to exactly describe the rim of the resting mesh's eyelids.  They need to be placed almost exactly between the outward-facing and eyeward-facing faces of the mesh.  The bones I see there are not placed carefully. (Additionally, it doesn't look there are enough of them, at least, not for the upper eyelid.  You've got like two bones for the top and six for the bottom.)